# where puting ForeignKey in django?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

one of the questions that came to my mind is that in a many-to-one relationship in `Django`, where should the `foreign key` be located? I mean, it should be in many or in part one?

For example, we have two classes, `post` and `comment`: in this case, where should the `ForeignKey` be located in the `comment` or `post` class?

`post model` :

```
class post(models.model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ManyToManyField("PostCategory", blank=True)
    caption = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
```

`comment model` :

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
          verbose_name=_('user'), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    text = models.TextField()
```

Now here is the `comment` field where the `foreign key` should be defined?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Foreign key must be used on the "Many" side of the [Many-to-one relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/).

In your question, you have `Post` and `Comment` models. Since each post can have many comments, you should put a foreign key into your `Comment` model.

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```